# How to put a new line in an ArrayList java

Tags: java, file

How to input a new line in an java String array.
  For example my input file is this:

```
   Student learns programming 
   java.Teacher rates 
   student.Nero gets ten.
```

and the output is in one line.
   Output:

```
  Student learns programming java.Teacher rates student.Nero gets ten.
```

my code used is this:

```
 File f=new File(s3);
      File _if=new File(s2);

      File _dic=new File(s4);
      f.createNewFile();

      FileInputStream _inputfile=new FileInputStream(_if.getAbsolutePath());
      BufferedReader _readfile=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_inputfile));
      String _str=_readfile.readLine();
      FileWriter _filewrite=new FileWriter(f);
      BufferedWriter _buffwrt=new BufferedWriter(_filewrite);
      int sum=0,sum2=0;
      ArrayList<String> _array=new ArrayList<String>();
            while (_str != null) {

                String[] _vect = _str.split(" ");
                int i;


                for (i = 0; i < _vect.length; i++) {

                    _array.add(_vect[i]);}


                _str =_readfile.readLine();



            }
```

Comment: Have you tried.. like.. a newline? `"\n"`

Comment: @MightyPork yes I tried.It just put the the character there

Comment: Where exactly do you want to put a new line?

Comment: How do you write the output - if that's where your problem is? All we see is that you store some string values into a List.

Comment: Please clarify what it is you want. You get `ArrayList` where each entry is one of the words in your input. What do you want to do with the newline? Do you want to output something with a newline? What exactly?

Comment: @AleksandrM well I want put a new line just after programming.

Comment: @RealSkeptic the list will be further used to write in a file,and I do not know how to make the new file exactly as the input one.So I thought I could get a new line in an ArrayList.

Comment: Where is `_str` being set?  I believe your issue is that the newlines are lost before the code you show.

Comment: Why do you split the input lines?

Comment: @CPerkins the program is quite long I didn't gave the full code just for that.The code works perfectly just it doesn't write the new file exactly as the input one.

Comment: @laune for each word to have its place in the ArrayList

Comment: It's `not` working perfectly if you're losing the newlines when you read the file, before the above code gets a chance.  But good luck.

Comment: @CPerkins gets initialized but I didn't paste that part.

Comment: You'll have to explain the purpose better. If you are doing something with that ArrayList before you write it to a file, adding newlines to it may make the part that works perfectly stop working. It would be best if you edited your question and gave the full text of your assignment, explain which part your ArrayList implements, and then we might be able to help you in the spirit of your assignment.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes indeed I am not very good at explaining.I edited the post.I do nothing with the ArrayList before,I just put the words of a file into a new file .I wanted to appear as the original   and I thought I could add a new line into an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

Take a look in [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File)) method, that reads a file straightforward to a List.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a "\n" string to the arraylist after the for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < _vect.length; i++) {
    _array.add(_vect[i]);
}
_array.add("\n");//this will add a new line character to the arraylist
```

Comment: Somewhere should be some constant for that. :)

Comment: @it returns a void file with adding "\n".

Comment: What are you outputting to a file?

Comment: I would actually recommend using `System.getProperty("line.separator");` to be sure the proper value is used.

Also, it is not a good convention to use underscores in front of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the newline character as a `String` to the list, I would append the newline to the String itself:

```
for (i = 0; i < _vect.length; i++) {
    _array.add(_vect[i] + "\n");
}
```

I do not think wasting allocation of memory by making the newline `String` a unique entry on the `List` is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If the whole intention of this assignment is to read the file and write it back, you don't really need an `ArrayList` at all. You can do something like:

```
while ( _str != null ) {
    _buffwrt.write( _str );
    _buffwrt.newLine();
}
```

This simply reads each line from the input file and writes it back to the output file.

But I suspect, from your code, that you actually want to do something with the words in this file. You didn't explain what it is you are doing. Maybe you want to count them, or maybe you want to translate them to something.

The important thing, though, is that you don't have to keep all the words of the whole file in an `ArrayList` together. You should do it for each line separately. You may even be able to work directly with the split array. For example, here is how you would count the words of the whole file, and still write each line separately.

```
int sum = 0;

while ( _str != null ) {


    String[] _vect = _str.split(" ");
    sum += vect.length;

    _buffwrt.write( _str );
    _buffwrt.newLine();
}
```

This adds the number of words in each line to the total of words after reading each line. But it still writes the original line to the output file as before.

If what you want to do is make changes to the words and write them back changed, you could do something like:

```
while ( _str != null ) {


    String[] _vect = _str.split(" ");

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < _vect.length; i++ ) {

        // Change _vect[i] in some way

        _vect[i] = ....;

        // Write a space if it's not the first word
        if ( i != 0 ) {
           _buffwrt.write( ' ' );
        }

        _buffwrt.write(vect[i]);

     }

    _buffwrt.newLine();
}
```

What you do here is split the line, work on each word, and then write it to the output file. You also write a space before it if it's not the first word.

The important point here is not to collect all the words in the file together, and then try to remember which word belonged to which line, or adding newlines to the `ArrayList`, which are not words and may affect the logic of your program. Instead, work on each line separately, and write it separately, and then you can add a newline at the end of processing.